# Is there a substance that hardens in water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, water

Im trying to invent a product that starts as a liquid but when exposed to water it hardens. Is there any chemicals that can cause this reaction??

Comment: Superglue, amongst many...

Answer (score 2):

Oh sure.  The most famous is calcium orthosilicate, otherwise known as Portland cement.  So what you're wanting to invent already exists in the form of concrete, which as you know is poured as a liquid, and reacts with water to produce a hard durable substance.  It's also extremely cheap, since the raw material is just a certain (common) type of rock.  So one way to go about your new invention is to think about how what you want to invent would differ from concrete.  You could start by thinking of concrete's limitations, and whether these are fundamental or could be fixed by some change in material  properties.